# Can the Realm Reborn launcher pause/resume the game download?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I just purchased Realm Reborn.

It seems like the launcher is trying to download around 9GB.

When it had around 50MB, I decided to cancel it and then restart it just to make sure that it was able to resume - because my internet connection is not quite stable.

It seems to me like the download begun at 0MB, rather than 50MB as expected.

Does this mean that the downloader can't pause/resume? I'm afraid that my connection will probably have a little downtime at least once during those 9GB.

Reading around  the web, I think I saw something about that the game is divided in 5 parts, and when it is done with one it will not have to download it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can, but it doesn't really tell you about it.

I was downloading the same update, and lost my network connection after downloading about 3 GBs.  When I restarted the launcher, the total amount it had to download was lower by the amount I had downloaded.

So there's no real way to pause, as such, except to shut down the launcher.  It probably won't have to redownload those 50MBs of yours, but the total amount to download is rounding to the nearest GB, I bet.

Comment: I can confirm this.  The progress meter just shows you what you need to download from the time you launched it (ignoring previous sessions) rather than the actual patch size.

Comment: Confirmed, interrupted at 4GB, then resumed to download the other 5GB rather than 9GB.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm once you login again after console goes into standby, it resumes with lower amount to download left, but that's only if you have downloaded a certain amount. In my case it needs just over 11 GB. When I downloaded like 4 GB and the console went into standby, when I resumed and logged in it started again but only needed around 6 GB.